# Referenced WebService not showing up when I attempt to debug my code

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, reference

I am in the process of attempting to consume a WCF webservice in my application, but after adding the service reference and the appropriate using statement, I am unable to compile my code, and I get the following error 11 times with 11 line numbers:

```
Error   7   The type name 'SignOnService' does not exist in the type 'FTXService.FTXService'    C:\Users\bdugan\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\FTXService\FTXService\Service References\SignOnService\Reference.cs   130 20  FTXService
```

I know the service exists since I have used it in PHP in the past, but I can't seem to figure out why it isn't working. Here is Reference.cs:

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//     Runtime Version:4.0.30319.237
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace FTXService.SignOnService {
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System;


[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Runtime.Serialization", "4.0.0.0")]
[System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute(Name="SimpleItem", Namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
public partial class SimpleItem : object, System.Runtime.Serialization.IExtensibleDataObject, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {

    [System.NonSerializedAttribute()]
    private System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject extensionDataField;

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.OptionalFieldAttribute()]
    private bool AuthenticatedField;

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.OptionalFieldAttribute()]
    private string[] ContractIDsField;

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.OptionalFieldAttribute()]
    private string MessageStringField;

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.OptionalFieldAttribute()]
    private string[] OwnerIDsField;

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.OptionalFieldAttribute()]
    private bool PasswordChangedField;

    [global::System.ComponentModel.BrowsableAttribute(false)]
    public System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject ExtensionData {
        get {
            return this.extensionDataField;
        }
        set {
            this.extensionDataField = value;
        }
    }

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
    public bool Authenticated {
        get {
            return this.AuthenticatedField;
        }
        set {
            if ((this.AuthenticatedField.Equals(value) != true)) {
                this.AuthenticatedField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("Authenticated");
            }
        }
    }

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
    public string[] ContractIDs {
        get {
            return this.ContractIDsField;
        }
        set {
            if ((object.ReferenceEquals(this.ContractIDsField, value) != true)) {
                this.ContractIDsField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("ContractIDs");
            }
        }
    }

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
    public string MessageString {
        get {
            return this.MessageStringField;
        }
        set {
            if ((object.ReferenceEquals(this.MessageStringField, value) != true)) {
                this.MessageStringField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("MessageString");
            }
        }
    }

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
    public string[] OwnerIDs {
        get {
            return this.OwnerIDsField;
        }
        set {
            if ((object.ReferenceEquals(this.OwnerIDsField, value) != true)) {
                this.OwnerIDsField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("OwnerIDs");
            }
        }
    }

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
    public bool PasswordChanged {
        get {
            return this.PasswordChangedField;
        }
        set {
            if ((this.PasswordChangedField.Equals(value) != true)) {
                this.PasswordChangedField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("PasswordChanged");
            }
        }
    }

    public event System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
        System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler propertyChanged = this.PropertyChanged;
        if ((propertyChanged != null)) {
            propertyChanged(this, new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}

[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
[System.ServiceModel.ServiceContractAttribute(ConfigurationName="SignOnService.ISignOn")]
public interface ISignOn {

    [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://tempuri.org/ISignOn/Authentication_Complex", ReplyAction="http://tempuri.org/ISignOn/Authentication_ComplexResponse")]
    FTXService.SignOnService.SimpleItem Authentication_Complex(string UserName, string Password);

    [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://tempuri.org/ISignOn/Authentication_Simple", ReplyAction="http://tempuri.org/ISignOn/Authentication_SimpleResponse")]
    FTXService.SignOnService.SimpleItem Authentication_Simple(string Parameter1, string Parameter2);

    [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://tempuri.org/ISignOn/Authentication_ChangePassword", ReplyAction="http://tempuri.org/ISignOn/Authentication_ChangePasswordResponse")]
    FTXService.SignOnService.SimpleItem Authentication_ChangePassword(string Parameter1, string Parameter2, string Parameter3);

    [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://tempuri.org/ISignOn/Authentication_Reset", ReplyAction="http://tempuri.org/ISignOn/Authentication_ResetResponse")]
    FTXService.SignOnService.SimpleItem Authentication_Reset(string Parameter1);
}

[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
public interface ISignOnChannel : FTXService.SignOnService.ISignOn, System.ServiceModel.IClientChannel {
}

[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
public partial class SignOnClient : System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<FTXService.SignOnService.ISignOn>, FTXService.SignOnService.ISignOn {

    public SignOnClient() {
    }

    public SignOnClient(string endpointConfigurationName) : 
            base(endpointConfigurationName) {
    }

    public SignOnClient(string endpointConfigurationName, string remoteAddress) : 
            base(endpointConfigurationName, remoteAddress) {
    }

    public SignOnClient(string endpointConfigurationName, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress) : 
            base(endpointConfigurationName, remoteAddress) {
    }

    public SignOnClient(System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding binding, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress) : 
            base(binding, remoteAddress) {
    }

    public FTXService.SignOnService.SimpleItem Authentication_Complex(string UserName, string Password) {
        return base.Channel.Authentication_Complex(UserName, Password);
    }

    public FTXService.SignOnService.SimpleItem Authentication_Simple(string Parameter1, string Parameter2) {
        return base.Channel.Authentication_Simple(Parameter1, Parameter2);
    }

    public FTXService.SignOnService.SimpleItem Authentication_ChangePassword(string Parameter1, string Parameter2, string Parameter3) {
        return base.Channel.Authentication_ChangePassword(Parameter1, Parameter2, Parameter3);
    }

    public FTXService.SignOnService.SimpleItem Authentication_Reset(string Parameter1) {
        return base.Channel.Authentication_Reset(Parameter1);
    }
}
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a class in the service called `FTXService`, embedded in a namespace also called `FTXService`. When generating a client proxy out of that service, the service generator of Visual Studio messes up. It generates code that seems to reference to the re-occurring namespace used in the servicerefence instead of the service class method to be called.

To solve this, rename the class of your service implementation to (for example) `FTXServiceImpl` and regenerate your client proxy (remove and add your service reference in the client project).

Comment: This isn't the problem (refer to the included reference.cs). The problem is he is trying to use a type which doesn't exist in that namespace. The client type is SignOnClient (not SignOnService) and is present in the Reference.cs. The code generator worked as expected.

Comment: IMHO the code generator did not work as expected, because it doesn't compile after generation. See the error at the top of the question. I have had sort of this problem before and was able to trace it back to a code generator issue as stated in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

When you use the Add Service Reference dialog in Visual Studio it usually asks you to specify a namespace. By default it is `ServiceReference1`. It also generates strongly typed proxy client classes that usually end up with. So the client proxy might look something like this:

```
using (var client = new ServiceReference1.SomeNamespace.SignOnServiceClient())
{
    ...
}
```

Simply right click on the generated service proxy and browse the source code to see what classes exactly were created.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Reference.cs you posted the service client is called SignOnClient so you'll want something like:

```
var client = new SignOnClient();
```

Or to fully-qualify it:

```
var client = new FTXService.SignOnService.SignOnClient();
```

In other words the type `SignOnService` does not exist in the namespace (this is what the error is telling you) but `SignOnClient` does.